# How to use "flex" and "gap" for a grid with different-sized items? (gap is not working)

Tags: css, flexbox, css-grid

My code:

```
<head>
    <style>
        *, *:before, *:after {
          box-sizing: border-box;
        }
        html{
          background-color: #aaa;
          width: 100%;
          height: 100%;
        }
        body {
          background-color: #aaa;
          width: 100%;
          height: 100%;
          margin: 0px;
          padding: 0px;
        }

        .item {
            background-color: #fff;
        }
        
        .d-flex-column {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
        }
        
        .d-flex-row{
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: row;
        }
        
        .w-100{
            width: 100%;
        }
        .h-100{
            height: 100%;
            }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="d-flex-row w-100 h-100" style="gap: 0.5em;">
      <div class="d-flex-column h-100" style="flex: 1; gap:0.5em;">
        <div class="item" style="flex:2;">2</div>
        <div class="item" style="flex:1;">1</div>
        <div class="item" style="flex:1;">1</div>
      </div>
      <div class="d-flex-column h-100 " style="flex: 1; gap:0.5em;">
        <div class="item" style="flex:3;">3</div>
        <div class="item" style="flex:1;">1</div>
      </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

And the result:
[image]

If you look closely, the height of the item at the right bottom is sized differently to the left one.
Can I even use "flex: x;" and "gap"?

I know that I can achieve the same with "display: grid;" but I want to understand what I am doing wrong with this one.

Answer (score 2):

This is because of the `gap` property: the left column have two `0.5em` gaps whereas the right one only has one. if you use `border` to separate your cells instead you won't have this problem.

```html
<head>
    <style>
        *, *:before, *:after {
          box-sizing: border-box;
        }
        html{
          background-color: #aaa;
          width: 100%;
          height: 100%;
        }
        body {
          background-color: #aaa;
          width: 100%;
          height: 100%;
          margin: 0px;
          padding: 0px;
        }

        .item {
            background-color: #fff;
        }
        
        .d-flex-column {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
        }
        
        .d-flex-row{
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: row;
        }
        
        .w-100{
            width: 100%;
        }
        .h-100{
            height: 100%;
            }
            
        .border {
            border: 1px solid black;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="d-flex-row w-100 h-100">
      <div class="d-flex-column h-100" style="flex: 1">
        <div class="item border" style="flex:2;">2</div>
        <div class="item border" style="flex:1;">1</div>
        <div class="item border" style="flex:1;">1</div>
      </div>
      <div class="d-flex-column h-100 " style="flex: 1">
        <div class="item border" style="flex:3;">3</div>
        <div class="item border" style="flex:1;">1</div>
      </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But your solution leads to the same problem at the bottom right gap. ;-)

Comment: It does in the preview, I don't know why, however it works if you open the preview in fullscreen or in a browser